# What about Firefox in Mac is altering the scroll event listener?

Tags: javascript, macos, firefox, html5-video

The full example is here: https://codepen.io/builtbyvern/pen/MWmLgqd?editors=0100

I'm attempting to build a video that animates to a part that matches the percent scrolled to. It works great in every browser except one: Firefox on MacOS.

It appears that Firefox is debouncing scroll events that integrate with video. I can see it usually updating once the scroll is done or moving very slowly. For those who don't want to open the codepen:

```
const video = document.getElementById('video');
const main = document.querySelector('main')
const viewportHeight = window.outerHeight
const mainDeets = main.getBoundingClientRect()
const scrollyHeight = mainDeets.height
const initialTopOffset = mainDeets.top
const adjustedHeight = scrollyHeight - initialTopOffset
let percentScrolled = 0


// required to get video length
video.onloadedmetadata = () => {
  const videoDuration = video.duration
  let current = video.currentTime

  window.addEventListener('scroll', () => {
    const gbcr = main.getBoundingClientRect()
    percentScrolled = gbcr.top / -adjustedHeight
    
    if (percentScrolled >= 0) {
      video.currentTime = videoDuration * percentScrolled
      
    } 
  })
}
```

This one is a pretty big headscratcher to me.

Comment: the codepen uses different code

Comment: apologies... I was testing out some other ideas. I've updated to match the question.

Comment: I read somewhere that ios safari doesn't emit the scroll event until you've stopped scrolling - but that doesn't explain firefox on macos - this is latest firefox? have you tried the dev version of firefox?

Comment: oh, a new firefox is coming today or tomorrow ... cross your fingers :p